# Change tab title for Wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress

I just completed a custom wordpress site for a client and am wondering how to change the tab title that you see at the top of the browser to display the name of the company instead of the whole url ... so in my example I want it to say Kirby's Moving Company instead of kirbysmovingco.com/ and then behind the name of the company id like it to display the page such as Kirby's Moving Company - Home even though it won't be visible in the actual tab since the company name is so long. I'm including a screenshot that shows how I want the tab to link by using another site that I've built and then showing the Kirby's Moving link and how it looks.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Any help is appreciated, thanks so much!

Comment: The `<title>` tag is shown there. Look in `head.php` in your theme folder, it's constructed by the `wp_title()` function

Comment: It's strange because the header.php file is the same for both sites but the tab titles display differently... I don't understant why :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

> Hello, try this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Customize_Screen (just go to Appearance_Customize_Screen > Site identity and modify the site title

[Source](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/edit-text-that-appears-in-a-browser-tab/)

Also you could also read [this](https://itstillworks.com/change-tab-name-wordpress-10648.html), It might help!

Comment: The title is what I want it to be but it still remains the same ... ? :/

Comment: Have you tried refreshing your browser cookies and images and then refresh page?

Comment: Yeah I've done that... the setup of both sites is literally the same. I don't understand why one is displaying correctly and the other incorrectly. It's strange.

Comment: Do you have any plugins that might be causing problems (ex. SEO by Yoast)?

Comment: I have Yoast installed on the MT Transport site (the one that displays correctly) but it isn't installed on the new site... so could that be it?

Comment: Try adding this between the title tags:

`<?php wp_title("",true); ?>`

You will also run into the issue of not having a page title if you are using a custom page as your homepage, the Wordpress Codex entry for Wp_Title suggests this bit of code if that's the case:

`<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php is_home() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title(''); ?></title>`

Comment: I'll try this out and let you know how it goes. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Okay so guess what worked? Setting up a Yoast SEO account just like I did with the first site made the title show properly!

Comment: Very strange haha. Nonetheless, thanks so much for your help!